# How to define "sections" in middle of URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC project for a restaurant with multiple locations. For SEO reasons, the decision was made to put our location names in the URL path itself, rather than as a subdomain (Ex: `Website.com/LocationName/{Controller}/{Action}`, instead of `LocationName.Website.com`).

We would also like the ability to accept requests without a location name (Ex: `Website.com/{Controller}/{Action}`, and either have the user select their nearest location, or forward the user to the proper URL if they have previously selected a location.)

We need this capability because each location has different items among other things, and we also need to load different background pictures based on the current location.

I have been thinking of different ways to do this for a few days now, but can't come up with a 'perfect' solution. What I came up with was to create a route for each location (about 10), as well as a "Catch-All" route with no location name specified like so:

```
' Routes with Store Name.
routes.MapRoute( _
    "HomeRoute-Loc1",
    "LocationName/{controller}/{action}",
    New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"})

' Routes with no Store Name.
routes.MapRoute( _
    "HomeRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"})
```

This seems to work Ok, except whenever I use Html Helpers (`@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Index", "Home")`), the URL always points to the first location's name in the URL (because it is the first matching Route defined).

My question is:
How can I set up a Routing system where the current location will always be displayed in the URL?
And once the user is in a location's "section", how can I get all of the links to point to URL's with that location's name in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specifically hard-code your location into your routes, make it dynamic like the rest of your parameters (controller, action, etc...)

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    "HomeRoute-Loc1",
    "{location}/{controller}/{action}",
    New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"})
```

I would then handle the "empty" location by sending your users to a different action on your Home controller allowing them to select the location and then passing that back through your actions.

Comment: But does that mean that I will need to have a "location" parameter in all of my actions?

Comment: yes, unfortunately. Unless you want to check RouteValues in every action

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I can inherit my controllers from a base class that will do such checks in the constructor. Do you think this would work? Would the handler just ignore the fact that the methods don't have a `location` parameter when it tries to figure out which action to route to?

Comment: actually, now that I'm thinking about it, leaving location empty wouldn't work in the situation that I described. You would need to define an explicit route and put it on top of all the others to define when you have no location. Your routes should work just fine without it being a parameter on every action and use a BaseController to pull location from the RouteValues. My preference would still be to edit your actions to support location, however

Comment: So I think I got a solution I defined two routes, one with, and one without the `{location}` variable. The one without `{location}`, I added a custom constraint class that automatically detects all Controllers in the project and creates a constraint that helps MVC properly figure out if the URL contains a location, or a controller name as it's first argument. This works well, the last hurdle is figuring out how I can make all of the links on pages routed with a `{location}` point to that same `{location}`. I wonder if @Html.ActionLink can do this, or if I should write my own helper function.